# Kubernetes pod resource limiting/quotas as a percentage of host resources (relative) rather than using absolute values?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-container

Resource limiting of containers in pods is typically achieved using something like below -

```
resources
  limits
    cpu "600m"
  requests
    cpu "400m"
```

As you see, absolute values are used above.
Now,

1. If the server/host has, say, 1 core then the total CPU computing power of the server is 1,000m. And the container is limited to 600m of computing power, which makes sense.
2. But, if the server/host has say 16 cores then the total CPU computing power of server is 16,000m. But the container is still restricted to 600m of computing power, which might not make complete sense in every case.

What I instead want is to define limits/requests as a percentage of host resources. Something like below.

```
resources
  limits
    cpu "60%"
  requests
    cpu "40%"
```

Is this possible in k8s either out-of-box or using any CRD's?

Comment: What`s the use case of this? It makes more sense to me to use core wise limits.

Comment: thomas, the purpose is described in the Q itself.  Say you want few pods (like tomcat or apache etc) to occupy the entire resources on a node/host. If you use absolute values like 400m or 800m you can not achieve it. But with relative quantities you can achieve it by simply stating 90% or 100%. Does not this approach sound simple.

Comment: thomas, further i wanted to understand the features or K8S - what it provides and what it does not. So this Q.

Comment: I agree with you, it would be much more convenient for app developers and cluster administrators, to be able to specific resource requests/limits in relative values, using `%` notation (e.g. percentage of Node's CPU Cores Allocatable). It's actually ever going question, and long discussed [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24925).